# How to add CSS class attribute for Html helper methods in asp.net mvc (VB.NET)?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, html-helper

Name:

```
<%= Html.TextBox("txtName", "20", new { @class = "hello" }) %>
```

I want that in VB.NET , is it .cssclass="hello" or is it something else?

Comment: It should just be how you've set it there.

Comment: u mean .cssclass="hello" ?? but its not working

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This works:

```
<%=Html.TextBox("TextName", "TextBox value", New With {.class = "theClass"})%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the "With" keyword, and a dot, as follows:

Comment: doh!  beat by 45 seconds?  /sigh